# Parallel lines diverge behind the observer in projective geometry

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Of course parallel lines converge at a point at infinity in projective geometry, but visually, they appear to diverge as one gets closer and closer to the start of one's vision, i.e. they diverge behind the observer. I can't find much about this fact. How is this dealt with in the different projective spaces?  Are there any interesting hyperbolic 'perspectives' on this fact?

Comment: All of space projects onto the projective plane.  That means that the space "behind the viewer" is also mapped onto the projective plane.  The rays behind the viewer will appear to converge at the same vanishing point as the rays in front of the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The usual notion of parallelism is foreign to projective geometry. We need to go back to definitions, and the best way to do this is to define a projective space $P(E)$ associated with a vector space $E$. A projective line $D_i$ is then by definition a projective linear manifold associated with a vector plane $P_i$ of $E$. And $$D_1\cap D_2=P(P_1)\cap P(P_2)=P(P_1\cap P_2)$$
If $P_1\neq P_2 $ then $P_1\cap P_2 $ is a vector line $D$ and $P(D)$ is a point of $P(E)$.

All these statements are easily illustrated in $E:=\mathbb R^3$:
[image]